# How to make an desired activity as home launcher from the application programmatically

Tags: java, android

I have two activities in my small android module, MainActivity and LauncherActivity. I have a checkbox and button in Mainactivity. When i clicked that button and if checkbox is checked then it navigates to launcher activity and set LauncherActivity as default home launcher and if checkbox is not checked then it navigates to LauncherActivity as simple navigation without making any change in application module.All of this must be done programatically.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We are not a code writing service, but a community of professional developers and enthusiasts helping others. Rather than posting a "please code this for me" request, ask a question instead - including showing us your code, explaining what you have done to try to resolve your issue, and clearly stating what exactly you're in need of assistance on. Here's a link explaining how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change launcher activity programmatically. What you can do is to write checkbox value to shared preferences and when the app starts check it, and then immidiately redirect to another activity.

Something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (SharedPrefsManager.isCheckboxSet()){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LauncherActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate `Activity` which will be entry point for your application. Let's call it `EntryPointActivity`. Declare it in the manifest with the launcher intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then in its `onCreate()` method you can make a decision which activity you really want to start, start it and call finish. For saving and retrieving which activity should be displayed after launch you can use `SharedPreferences` or any other storage.